# AngularJS Filter on property from JSON/Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am new to Angular and I am building a simple list (Also with ionic, but its using angular) of ice creams. I get the data from a JSON file with objects (an object for each ice cream). All objects have a property called "beschikbaar" what will be set to "Ja" or "Nee" (can also be true or false if thats making the job easier to do). In the list I made with a ng-repeat I would like to show only the items where the property "beschikbaar" is set to "Ja" or true. Otherwise I would like to hide them. I can't get it done.

Is it possible to fix this with just a simple filter in the view or must there be a custom filter to do this? I have no exp. with custom filters.

I have tried all kind of things, the filter in the view now is just an example of a try.

My code

VIEW

```
     <ion-item ng-repeat="item in icecreams | filter: {item.beschikbaar}:Ja" class="item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
        <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ item.info }}</p>
        <h4>{{ item.type }}</h4>
        <h4>In de winkel tot: {{ item.end_date }}</h4>
      </ion-item>
```

JSON

```
[

        {
            "name" : "Aardbei Sorbet",
            "type" : "Sorbet",
            "info" : "Aardbei sorbet ijs is een frisse en zoete ijssmaak. Heerlijk voor in de zomer met bijvoorbeeld slagroom en chocolade ijs. Gemaakt met Hollandse Aardbeien.",
            "end_date" : "Maandag 17 Juli",
            "ingre" : "Hollandse aardbeien, melk, water, vanille roomijs",
            "suikervrij" : "Nee",
            "gluten" : "Nee",
            "beschikbaar" : "Ja"             
        },

        {
            "name" : "Mango Sorbet",
            "type" : "Sorbet",
            "info" : "Mango sorbet ijs is een exotische smaak. Met dit ijs krijg je het gevoel alsof je in een ver en exotisch land bent. Gemaakt met echte mango. Lekker te combineren met Ananas ijs.",
            "end_date" : "Maandag 17 Juli",
            "ingre" : "Mango stukjes, citroensap, water, vruchtvlees ananas",
            "suikervrij" : "Nee",
            "gluten" : "Ja",
            "beschikbaar" : "Ja"                        
        },

        {
            "name" : "Tompouchen ijs",
            "type" : "Special",
            "info" : "Een hema naast de winkel is garantie voor lekker ijs. Tompouchen ijs is een leuk experiment geworden. De romige smaak komt er in terug en ik heb er voor gezorgd dat hij niet extreem zoet is!",
            "end_date" : "Maandag 17 Juli",
            "ingre" : "Tompouchen, cakebeslag, room, melk, water",
            "suikervrij" : "Nee",
            "gluten" : "Ja",
            "beschikbaar" : "Ja"             
        },

        {
            "name" : "Drop ijs",
            "type" : "Snoep",
            "info" : "Ijs van drop, hoe tof is dat? Zoet van smaak, met een authentieke drop smaak. Gemaakt op basis van drop en vanille ijs.",
            "end_date" : "Maandag 17 Juli",
            "ingre" : "Tompouchen, cakebeslag, room, melk, water",
            "suikervrij" : "Nee",
            "gluten" : "Ja",
            "beschikbaar" : "Nee" 
        }

]
```

Controller

```
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.icecreams = data;
  });

}]);
```

I know there are a lot of questions of this subject but I just can't get it to work. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: why not just apply that business logic of filtering within the `success` function? It would be even better to handle this on the server side if you're not always just pulling in a static file (less data transfer, faster etc..).

Comment: @KevinFriedheim Because In the future I would like to show a list with available items and items that are not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this without any filters, just use an `ng-if`.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in icecreams" class="item-thumbnail-left" href="#" ng-if="item.beschikbaar == 'Ja'">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
        <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ item.info }}</p>
        <h4>{{ item.type }}</h4>
        <h4>In de winkel tot: {{ item.end_date }}</h4>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Is this the best/correct way of doing it instead of filtering? I am not an expert on AngularJS but I would like the most correct way possible.

Comment: I wouldn't consider what you're trying to achieve to be 'filtering'. Filtering indicates to me that the user is inputting something that should display your list differently. Here you're just choosing what you want to initially display. An `ng-if` is sufficient here. A filter would be overkill.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your time :) It is working perfectly fine. I've edited your question to match it with ionic, because if I add another div inside the `ion-item` div it will mess up the style. Thanks!

Comment: @Gijsberts, Excellent glad you were able to get it working! I usually use an inner div just because sometimes it can be confusing to a non-angular developer to realize that the `ng-if` doesn't negate the entire `ng-repeat` statement.